# New account or delete my posts?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accounts, deleted-users

After being in denial for many posts, I’ve learnt that my approach to asking/answering questions must be making a lot of mods and Stack Overflow members quite angry. I’m anxious that I’m getting quite a bad reputation from those who kept having to tell me off. I’ve gradually learnt many lessons.

Sickened by my posts, I wish to repent my sins and start over, but I want to ask one more possibly lazy/silly question before doing so:

Is it okay to start a new account/email or would it be more appropriate to just delete my posts?

Comment: ..or change the icon and display name

Comment: Deleting your posts could cause more problems. Now that you've learned how to answer/ask just do better from now on and clean up any "bad" posts that you can.

Comment: Cheers @Plutonix that implies I do not delete the posts? If so then I'm still stuck, because people can view my crappy posts... if I delete my posts the moral problem is that those posts may have benefited some people... there may be some pearls amongst swine

Comment: cheers @codeMagic that was a possibility... admittedly frustrating though, but thanks for the guiding opinion

Comment: yes, the bad posts will be associated with the new name, but people wont avoid posts based on the name/icon displayed.  they'd have to research the account to recognize you by posts

Comment: but @Plutonix I have...

Comment: Unless you really have acted like an ass, no one will care who you are if you change your ways with your current account. Plenty of high rep users started bad.

Comment: I did act as an ass in many comments, I still get tempted to act like an ass... and being stuck with this assey account encourages me to stay like an ass...

Comment: If you're an ass then you will be an ass whether your name is "hello_there_andy", "I_love_unicorns", or anything else. Leave your account and quit being an ass

Comment: I think we either need to move this to chat, or somebody needs to give me an answer...

Comment: @codeMagic So there's no such thing as a "conditional ass"? :P

Comment: @Mysticial I guess there is because I'm quite pleasant when I'm not around people ;)

Comment: exactly.. as @Mysticial says, I might just need a name change, post deletion spree or new account... which one?

Comment: First, I think you should [read this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSarcasm&ei=qvZzU6rUDY6hyAT7_oHoBQ&usg=AFQjCNEh5L-dxk1mRRkwXN1oHMLgnzAVpw&sig2=wtEIi2-r6pvcElKBUD8hBg&bvm=bv.66699033,d.aWw) then go on a delete spree so you are question banned instead of listening to my original advice

Comment: You have a mixed (but not terrible) past, and the community cares very little about it anyways. Changing your name/picture could help alleviate any "negative" associations other users might have with you if you were really a "ass" to them. Other than that, be nice and post good questions/answers, you'll be fine.

Comment: If you delete your account, you will also punish the people that you have upvoted.

Comment: Yeah that was an accepted answer because it got me off my ass and forced me to read the rules (again) and other posts related to etiquette. I tried to delete and flag some posts. Somebody serially downvoted a lot of my crap posts after this. :( and then the serial downvotes were reversed by the holy Unicorns. Praise be to the Unicorns! Hail the Unicorns!!!!! HAAAAIL!!!!

Comment: Really, why can't you just move on from your mistake? You're better now, and you know it. Plus, don't worry what other people say about you and your question. If you think it's a good question, then it's bound that other people do too.

Comment: @pnuts I decided to keep my account and display name, ignore the past crappy posts and move on just as active as before. I also didn't grovel/ask for crappy posts to be dissassociated with this account. I would have made a new account if it wasn't for the accepted answer/comments by you lot

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Technically, you can "start over" without doing either.  Each post is largely judged on its own merits (or lack thereof), rather than on its author.  (There are a couple exceptions, but they generally involve the author being abusive.)  So if you do the right thing from here on out, those first posts will hardly even be noticed.

If you really don't want your past to even potentially haunt you, though, you are allowed to make another account.  The main rules are that you aren't allowed to use multiple accounts to (a) get around a ban,  or (b) vote on your other accounts' posts.  (Note also, when you switch to another account, your reputation doesn't go with you.)

Alternatively, if you'd like to keep your current account and just get rid of a couple of the worst posts, you could ask to have your name removed from them.  You won't own them anymore, so they won't show up in your history.  I don't know if they'll dissociate all your posts, and/or how much groveling will be involved...but eh.  You could ask.

---

Note, in none of that was deleting your posts even mentioned as an option.  That's because it's not, really.  Besides the fact that you *can't* delete a lot of them, even the ones you *do* delete can adversely affect the site's idea of your overall post quality.  If that gets too low, you could end up banned from asking and/or answering questions.  It'd be better to create a new account or remove your name from the posts, and better still to keep them (and ideally, to edit them so that they're worthy of upvotes) and show you've learned your lesson.  :)

Comment: As far as I am aware mods don't have the power to just remove a name from any arbitrary post. They can convert it to CW but they are unlikely to want to do this on a number of questions for one user.

Comment: Moderators can't remove your name from the questions/answers, but can bring it to the attention of people who can according to: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746) but I don't really think that should be used for getting rid of bad posts and is more effort than it's worth for everyone involved.

Answer (score 24):

Let's get the obvious stuff out of the way first. You can't delete **all** your posts even if you wanted to. Many of your questions have up voted answers so it is impossible for you to delete them.  Even deleting *some* of them might put you on the quick path to a question ban.

Creating a new account is possible but if you handle it wrong, you will just trigger a merge and you'll get your old account (and posts) associated with you new account.  And even worse, if you don't trigger a merge and you ever interact with your old posts (such as voting), you'll likely get yourself in trouble and possibly suspended for voting fraud.

Your best option is to [just stop being an ass](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254907/new-account-or-delete-my-posts#comment21472_254907) and start asking good questions. The community has a short memory and positive contributions will overshadow most anything you have done in your past.

Comment: Community has no memory unless you are influential. I started with horribly dumb questions (sometimes).

Comment: Over time, like everyone else, I improved my questions and answer. Updated my old questions etc.

Answer (score 12):

When I view a question and I'm choosing between upvote/downvote and or answering it - I don't go and check your other questions first. Its only done on the merits of the question at hand.

**Just make your next question (and the next, and ...) a good one and it will all work out.**

Answer (score 6):

If you are truly reformed and determined to make a new start and have performed an adequate amount of self-flagellation (*no - don't tell me I don't want to know about it!!*) then you could ask for your account to be removed.

This removes your account (there is a stand-down period of 24 hours) and anonymizes all your posts *for the site the account was removed from*. To do this flag one of your posts for ♦ moderator attention and state your wishes in the custom reason. Your old posts will then live and die of their own accord and will get cleaned up accordingly.

Once this is done you can start a new account. You'll be starting from scratch and have to build up your rep and privileges again.

Comment: ahh didn't know that the posts stay there

Comment: @hello_there_andy Speaking as a mod (from a different site) this is possibly the best option. Be aware not to abuse it though - without going in to it mods still have tools and powers ;)

Comment: you're scary LOL

Comment: You can also email StackOverflow to have your account deleted.