# Specific suggestions on editing my questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am a novice both in programming and SO.

About 8 months ago, I first met stackoverflow after searching in google. I was mesmerized by both this idiosyncratic website and answers. So I signed up immediately and I **didn't** read the questions in *Help Center* carefully (that makes me **regret** later). So soon I ask some bad questions . So I was voted down. After that I began to read some terms about my beloved sites in order to fit in it.

Recently, I asked some questions that was marked duplicate (althouth I don't think so, it seems that I didn't express clear enough, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502050/declaring-variables-at-the-beginning-have-better-performance-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364465/differences-between-abcde-and-abcdede-de-in-java)) and I was voted down.

Just now, I am editing my old questions and want them to be good questions using the answer in this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). But after editing one of questions about minimax algorithm I was voted down again (I really don't understand, maybe for ["fix my code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788)). In order to ask questions, I try to delete the post. However, I was banned even I delete it (filter still take it in account).

I really love SO. *So I wonder if anyone could point out how should I **change** my those downvoted question: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502050/declaring-variables-at-the-beginning-have-better-performance-in-java), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364465/differences-between-abcde-and-abcdede-de-in-java), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456898/java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-when-use-and), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796620/javahow-can-calculation-happens-before-reading-data)* (or any other questions if you want)?  Thanks.

**Related:** [New account or delete my posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254907/new-account-or-delete-my-postsc), [Before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question), and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

**Edit:** The following is some advice I received so I conclude it to remind me and other newbie:

1. Begin with Google and **Search** more. Turning to SO if other sites can't solve you problem (remember to show your searching efforts)

2.Improve your searching skills ([Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)) and try to search in different expressions/terms.

3.Read your question carefully before you post it.

**More posts** may help : [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for/262533#262533), [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow)

Thanks all of you again. You give me the sense of belonging and it's really a warm community.

Comment: You should read this [excellent post for newcomers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262533/2982225)

Comment: +1 For actually caring and coming back to fix-up your old posts.

Comment: @Payeli Thanks, I am learning from it and I really should improve my searching skill and finding some other help resources.

Comment: @Sam Should I totally substitute the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495326/comparison-between-for-foreach-and-iterator-why-the-for-is-faster-than-for-ea) for a better benchmark ?

Comment: @Tony I wouldn't. Your post is basically asking why you got those results for *that particular* benchmark. So changing the question with an improved benchmark will invalidate the answer. Run the benchmarks by all means, and *if* the results are **accurate** and different from what you got before, then it would probably be a good idea to post a different question (if you can't find a similar post of course).

Comment: Just because I noticed while looking at some of your questions: You should probably consider to accept some answers too. And: Don't ask questions that can be answered by using google. But I respect your attempt to improve your questions, hope you'll get along.

Comment: Ok, I've edited what I could. This was mostly grammatical clarification and reformatting to standards established in the help pages for posting code. Have a look over it. I enjoy this sort of challenge. If you don't mind my asking, what is your native language? The curious, yet consistent, errors were rather unlike anything I've seen before. Please don't take that wrong way. In comparison to what I've experienced, your English is quite good.

Comment: @Theolodis Thanks for your advice. I will never make that stupid mistakes. Thanks again.

Comment: @ouflak Thanks for your patient editing and my native language is Chinese. I am learning the right way and try to avoid. Thanks for your credits, again.

Comment: I know other people already said this, but +1 for actually wanting to improve. The question/answer ban is in place because a majority of the time people *don't* improve. Thank you for wanting to improve. :)