# Would flagging my question to off-topic affect asking question

Tags: discussion

When editing some of my questions, I find one of questions is off-topic according to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I know if I delete it, it may affect my asking question on SO.

So, I wonder if I flag it for **closing->off-topic** will affect it? Thanks.

**Edit:** Actually, because I didn't read the tips in help center, [I made many mistakes past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262751/specific-suggestions-on-editing-my-questions). So, I wonder which may be better, vote to closing or just delete it.

Comment: All your past activity is take into account for deciding on question bans and such. Still, if you don't have predominately bad contributions, you can ignore that without danger.

Comment: Another possibility is to edit it so it is **on-topic**. Also, what the @Deduplicator said

Comment: @codeMagic But the topic of the question is not suitable for SO. If I edit it to on-topic, it may be a totally different question and editing page doesn't suggest doing so.

Comment: Ah, ok, that does change things. Then leaving it be or deleting it would be appropriate. Hopefully, you have learned from " I made many mistakes past." and it won't be a factor. Voting to close it isn't going to help at all, AFAIK

Comment: @codeMagic So do you mean I may better delete it directly?

Comment: If you've realized it's off-topic then I would say so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ... far enough away from the block that while you should keep it in mind, you're not likely to encounter it again if you continue asking good questions that receive a positive score.

Just leaving it as it is probably isn't going to hurt anything, these things tend to be closed and ultimately deleted over time. Anyone that has used the site for an appreciable amount of time *probably* has at least one question that was iffy, at best, when it comes to being on-topic.

We're also working on fixing the question block system so that it slows you down to the extent that you ask questions that don't go so well, but allows you to quickly recover with a few good questions, because we don't want folks getting into the same sort of decision paralysis that you're demonstrating. It shouldn't, well, *be* that complicated and the (needed) secrecy behind how the blocks work just amplifies your hesitance to do good things for the site.

I'd just leave it for now, let nature take its course and if it becomes an issue for you before we manage to get blocks fixed, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and let us know. We won't let something unsalvageable that you wrote *prior* to getting a lot better at asking get in your way of using the site successfully. I don't think it will present a problem, though - you've got a fair amount of 'hit points' before you have to worry about the block again, which continue to increase with each good post that you write.

Comment: Great answer. But I have already deleted it for following the suggestion of a user..